# SQL Query to categorise accounts into x and other

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2012 DB and I have the following tables:

- CNSMR_ACCNT (consumer accounts)
- CMSR_ACCNT_TAG (Tags assigned to consumer accounts)
- TAT (The tags table)

An account may have several tags assigned to it to indicate various characteristics.  I am trying to categorise my accounts into 3rd party accounts and other.  So if an account has the tag '3PTSALE', irrespective of what other Tags it may have, it's considered 3rd party.  Accounts that do not have the tag '3PTSALE' are categorised as 'OTHER'.

Eg say there is an account 1233 which has tags 'ABC', 'DEF', 'KLY' and '3PTSALE' then this account must be categorised as 3PTSALE.  In contrast account 1234 has tags 'ABC', 'DEF', 'NOP', 'JKL' and this account is categorised as 'OTHER' since it doesn't have the tag '3PTSALE'.

Here is some code I have written so far but I am not yet able to figure how to categorise the data.  Doesn't work but hopefully tells you what I am trying to achieve.

```
Select ca.cnsmr_accnt_id, tag_shrt_nm, 
case 
ca.cnsmr_accnt_id in 
(select cat.cnsmr_accnt_id from cnsmr_accnt_tag cat inner join tag t on 
cat.tag_id = t.tag_id 
where tag_shrt_nm = '3PTSALE' and cat.cnsmr_accnt_sft_delete_flg = 'N') 
when  then '3PTSALE'
Else 
'Other'
End  as 'SIE_CATEGORY'

from cnsmr_accnt ca inner join
cnsmr_accnt_tag cat on ca.cnsmr_accnt_id = cat.cnsmr_accnt_id 
inner join tag t on cat.tag_id = t.tag_id 
where cat.cnsmr_accnt_sft_delete_flg = 'N'
```

Comment: no it does not tell us what you are trying to achieve.  WHAT ARE YOU TRYING TO ACHIEVE???

Comment: are they guaranteed to have at least one tag?  if not, you'll want a `left outer` join instead of an `inner` join to the `tag` table

Answer (score 0):

If you're already joined to the relevant tables could you not simplify your case statement like this:

```
case  when tag_shrt_nm = '3PTSALE' then '3PTSALE' else 'Other' end as [SIE_CATEGORY]
```

That way you shouldn't need a sub query in the case statement

Comment: The problem is that an account can have MANY tags, so if I did this, I would get back that an account eg 123355 is both 3PTSALE and also OTHER.

Comment: You wouldn't, because 1 tag can only have 1 value. The idea of comparing to a single value does not make sense for this structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use the EXISTS() function in your CASE statement:

```
...
CASE
  WHEN EXISTS( 
    SELECT * FROM TAG t2 WHERE t2.Tag_id=t.Tag_id AND t2.tag_shrt_nm = '3PTSALE' 
  ) THEN '3PTSALE'
  ELSE 'Other'
END AS 'SIE_CATEGORY'
...
```

This basically says, "if there exists a tag with the name '3PTSale' that joins to the row I'm currently looking at, then return '3PTSale'.   If no such row exists, return 'Other'".

Comment: Perhaps better to get the tags into a CTE first to avoid re-querying for each account row?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want I would do it like this:

```
WITH THIRDPTAG AS
(
   SELECT cnsmr_accnt_id, tag_shrt_nm 
   FROM cnsmr_accnt_tag 
   WHERE tag_shrt_nm = '3PTSALE' and cat.cnsmr_accnt_sft_delete_flg = 'N'
)
Select ca.cnsmr_accnt_id, tag_shrt_nm, 
       coalesce(3PTITEMS.tag_shrt_nm,'Other') as SIE_CATEGORY
from cnsmr_accnt ca 
left join THIRDPTAG on ca.cnsmr_accnt_id = THIRDPTAG.cnsmr_accnt_id 
inner join cnsmr_accnt_tag cat on ca.cnsmr_accnt_id = cat.cnsmr_accnt_id 
inner join tag t on cat.tag_id = t.tag_id 
where cat.cnsmr_accnt_sft_delete_flg = 'N'
```